# how to get the count ONLY in a specific time period

Tags: mysql

I NEED TO get the count of vehicles who appear more than 10times/ week only showing up between '2012-07-24' and '2012-09-02' and . 
i tried :

```
select distinct * from anpr_in where location='a35.1.ob.1' and date(time) 
between '2012-07-24'and '2012-09-02' group by plate having count(plate)>10;
```

but it doesnt filter the cars which still appear out of the period.

the table looks like:

```
plate           location       number    time
T971JUR     A3024.7.IB.1         96     2012-05-13 18:06:17
HN52YWE     A3024.13.OB.1        94     2012-05-13 18:09:53
R179NBM     A335.6.OB.1          90     2012-05-13 18:08:55
WV07EAX     A35.1.IB.1           91     2012-05-13 18:05:09
HF02NFH     A334.14.IB.1         94     2012-05-13 18:06:43
HK11BHE     A33.5.IB.2           96     2012-05-13 18:07:52
39341       A35.1.OB.1           0      2012-05-13 18:08:09
CP61PCZ     A35.1.IB.1           96     2012-05-13 18:07:04
LM06UKN     A3024.8.IB.1         96     2012-05-13 18:06:44
3B001       A35.1.OB.1           0      2012-05-13 18:07:49
WG10YCT     A3024.13.OB.1        90     2012-05-13 18:08:04
HY60XTE     A3024.8.IB.1         93     2012-05-13 18:05:31
M397BLA     A334.14.OB.1         92     2012-05-13 18:06:57
```

Comment: Remove the `distinct` keyword. `GROUP BY` already makes it distinct.

Comment: Do you want to see cars that appeared at least 10 times in any week in the period, or 10 times per week in every week? What is a "week" - what day does your week start on? (The standard is Sunday). Also your attempt doesn't consider the concept if "week" at all - is it something different again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return the count of plates meeting your criteria

```
SELECT COUNT(*) plate_count
FROM (SELECT plate
      FROM anpr_in
      WHERE location='a35.1.ob.1'
      AND DATE(time) BETWEEN '2012-07-24' AND '2012-09-02'
      GROUP BY plate
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 10) x
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/baec9/1)

You don't need `DISTINCT` because `GROUP BY` already reduces it down to distinct plate numbers.

Comment: Thank you. but when i tried your query, there was an error,saying every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: Works fine for me, see the fiddle.

Comment: and i have checked from the answer, the car still appear out of the period.

Comment: The sample data you supplied has no dates in the period, and I got 0 in my fiddle, as expected.

Comment: I have no idea. What happens when you try to run it?

Comment: when i copy this query my workbench, it shows some error in syntax and i cannot run it. so i change the 'x' into 'as tempt' and add ';'. it works, but the same results with mine before....

Comment: I don't use workbench, I just use the mysql CLI tool or sqlfiddle. I can't explain why workbench works differently for you.

Comment: i tried today, it works. but could you show me how can i see all of plates fulfill the conditions. thank you

Comment: and one more thing is, does the results contains the time not within 7/24 to 09/02

Comment: If you want to see all the plates, just use the subquery. Your question said you wanted to see the count, that's why I added the `SELECT COUNT(*)` outer query. The result only contains the time within 7/24-09/02.

Comment: I just noticed something. The question said "10 times/week", but this query is 10 times in the whole period 7/24-9/2. Which do you really want? If it's 10/week, do you mean 10 times in each week during that period, 10 times in any one week during that period, or averaging 10 times per week (the period is about 5.5 weeks, so that's 55 total times)?